# Full panel break for highly skewed ggplot2 histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, facet, skew

I have highly skewed histogram generated using ggplot2.

[image: skewed histogram]

I would like split the x-axis of the histogram into two panels. One with x<50 and another x=>50 in order to detect any underlying pattern if any. So the first panel will have y-axis from 0 to around 500000 and x-axis from 0 to 50. The second panel with y-axis from 0 to around 100  and x-axis 50 to 350.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just facet on the condition:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~(carat > 3), scale = 'free')
```

[image]

Comment: This works great! May I know how do I change the title on each panel from FALSE and TRUE?

Comment: Make a new variable first, name the factor the levels appropriately. E.g. `diamonds$my_condition <- factor(diamonds$carat > 3, c(TRUE, FALSE), c('label1', 'label2')); ggplot(....) + ..... + facet_wrap(~my_condition, ......)`